# Xbox Live Creators Program - Games Category

Tags: live, xbox

I am tring to release a game to xbox using the Xbox Live Creators Program.
Trouble is it says to enable the creators program you have to list under the 'games' category in properties.
But there is no 'games' category! Any ideas or advice very much welcomed

added as MSIX or PWA app, also tried adding as game